# Is a 3 seat Microlight build possible?

Tags: ultralight, uk

Many Microlights have weights of no more than 450kg, as that was the old weight limit. Now that the limit is 650kg, it seems to me that would be enough weight to add an extra seat (80kg for the passenger and 120kg for the added seat and fuselage weight).

Is there any reason this can't be done? If not, are there custom manufacturers that would facilitate this?

Comment: Considering your last couple of questions have been followed with a youtube notification on my phone, I'm fully expecting a YT vid of you now with a garden chair strapped into the back of that C42 :D

Comment: @Jamiec haha :D Not a bad idea ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### TL;DR NO

From [the British Microlight Aircraft Association web site](https://www.bmaa.org/about-microlighting/exactly-what-is-a-microlight-):

> CURRENT UK DEFINITION/S
>
> 19th August 2021 - Air Navigation Order Update (600kg - LIGHT SPORT MICROLIGHTS)
>
> A UK Microlight Aeroplane is one designed to carry **not more than two persons** which has a Maximum Total Weight Authorised (MTWA) not exceeding:
>
> - 600 kg for a single seat and two seat landplane (Permit to Fly).
> - **650 kg for a single seat and two seat amphibian or floatplane** (Permit to Fly).
> - Stalling speed at the maximum weight authorised not exceeding 45 knots (Calibrated Airspeed).

In other words, the legal definition includes "two seats". The increase 650 kg for an amphibian or floatplane (was 495 kg) or 600 kg for a landplane (was 450 kg) doesn't change the maximum seating capacity.